# Logstash date parse failure with milliseconds since epoch

Tags: date, parsing, logstash

Logstash is not able to parse milliseconds since epoch and returns me an parse failure. There are no whitspaces in the content of the timestamo field in the xml and logstash selects the right value.

```
filter {
    xml {
            source => "message"
            remove_namespaces => true
            store_xml => false
            xpath => ["//event/@timestamp", "@time_since_epoch"]
    }

    date {
            match => [ "@time_since_epoch","UNIX_MS" ]
            target => "@time"
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

sample xml data line:

```
<event timestamp="1494599590213" ><message>Dummy message</message></event>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the value extracted from the xpath is put in an array (see: `"@time_since_epoch":["1494599590213"]` with the stdout plugin and the json codec).

So you'll need to access the time as an array element:

```
date {
        match => [ "[@time_since_epoch][0]","UNIX_MS" ]
        target => "@time"
}
```

Comment: Oh that was a left over from testing. Actually it is no longer in the code snippet. I also have my code adjusted accordingly.
Still it doesn't pare the date

Comment: @JohannesJ Ok, I don't have any other idea. Perhaps you could add a sample of the lines causing the problem. Also are you sure it's coming from the date filter? It might also be caused by something else in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your support... I added a sample line. I am pretty sure cause the output is the right value, but still a number and not parsed. And there ist also the date parse failure flag in the added document in elastic search

Comment: @JohannesJ Okay, found it. You have to access the `@time_since_epoch` as an array